# how to get view controller storyboard id or restortionIdentifier in backwards navigation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

In my navigation I have a rootViewController (AController), a second ViewController (BController) and a third one (CController).
I can navigate my app by pushing A --> B --> C.

When I go back from C --> B, in `BController:viewdidLoad` how can I get I'm navigating from C and not from A?

I tried to use `self.presentedViewController.restorationIdentifier` but it always return me the identifier of AController, not the CController one.

Should I use the storyboardID property? how can I do that?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice for such application would be to use a `UINavigationController` for navigation. If you are navigating using `UINavigationController` then viewDidLoad will only get called when you go from A to B but will not be called when you go back from C to B controller

Comment: Agreed.  Here's an image of the UIViewController life cycle to help your understanding. http://i.stack.imgur.com/eYCHy.jpg

Comment: I need to get this information in `(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` event endeed... This is raised even in my backwards navigation...

Comment: One way to do this is to have a NSString in the appdelegate class and update the NSString with your desired value of A,B,or C in the viewDidAppear function of each controller. Then you can access which class was last called: A or C when you access it in viewDidAppear.

Comment: But it isn't a good practice to have global variables in your AppDelegates so you can alternatively use `NSUserDefaults` for this

Comment: Thank you Khawar, I used your suggestion about NSUserDefaults!

Answer (score 2):

Try using delegation to set a property in B When loading C and going back to B again. 
Also, as @khawar-ali mentioned, `viewDidLoad` only gets called when loading the view controller for the first time hence `viewDidLoad` method won't get called when going back from C. Try `ViewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear` instead? :/